# Selecting rows of a data frame when the column of the dataframe contains multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas data frame in which the "***genres***" column has multiple values separated by **"|"**. I have put an image of it below.

Dataframe containing movie details:

[image]

If I use the split function, it will be converted to a list which is unhashable.

Now I want to select rows of the data frame only when the **"*genres*"** has the word **"Action"** in it? How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df = df[df['genres'].str.contains("Action")]
```

Example:

```
df = {'genres' : ('Action', 'crime', 'Action|crime', 'Romance|Action', 'Comedy'),'runtime' : (1,3,5,6,7)}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Output:

```
           genres  runtime
0          Action        1
2    Action|crime        5
3  Romance|Action        6
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise this. What if one genre is "Action" and another is "Action&Adventure" ?

Comment: Good point.. but for the example he showed should be ok. Or maybe he would like to keep also "Action&Adventure"

Comment: how about this, `df = df[df['genres'].str.contains('|'.join(["Action","Adventure"])`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution using `set`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'genres': ['A|B|C|D', 'A|B|C', 'B|D']})

res = df[df['genres'].str.split('|').apply(set) >= {'D'}]

print(res)

    genres
0  A|B|C|D
2      B|D
```

This can be naturally extended to multiple genres:

```
res = df[df['genres'].str.split('|').apply(set) >= {'A', 'B'}]

print(res)

    genres
0  A|B|C|D
1    A|B|C
```